# Writing values of various data types onto a text file for querying

Tags: java, text

What would be an ideal constructs / design for a program intended for querying lines of strings from a text file as a database? My main problem here is how do I make an object holding values of different data types (UUID, string, string, double, double, int) be written as a single package onto a text file of which these data will also be queried. I'm thinking of an array-like container for these values so that when queried, the output would print out the data in that package.

Comment: If you need queries, why don't you use a database? If you don't need queries, you could use XML or JSON to represent your objects. There are dozens of ways to transform Java objects to these formats.

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason for wanting to save to and query from a text file? Is it to avoid setting up a database daemon?

You have a few options, depending on what you're trying to achieve and the reasons for doing so.

1. You could serialise your data constructs into text files which can then be unserialised directly into the original data types later.
2. You could also use a non-SQL solution, such as MongoDB, that would save your data to text files too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you do not need **efficient** querying, I think the best for you would be to use [JSON](http://www.json.org/) format. Take a look at [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library. It does nice JSON to object mapping and serialization.

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/) you can find a nice 2-minutes guide with example.